# Dependency injection for DelegatingHandler with multiple constructor parameters and options

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm trying to use dependency injection for a `DelegatingHandler` that holds 2 interfaces and 1 string.

```
public class MessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageHandler> _logger;
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MessageHandler(ILogger<MessageHandler> logger, ISomeService someService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _someService = someService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Doing some other logic with {Name}");
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        _someService.DoSomething(Name);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I am adding this `DelegatingHandler` to an `HttpClient` via `IHttpClientFactory`

```
services.AddHttpClient("github")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.github.com"); })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MessageHandler>(); // I want Name property to be 'github'
```

However I also want to use the `MessageHandler` with multiple `HttpClient` with different `Name`s

```
services.AddHttpClient("twitter")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.twitter.com"); })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MessageHandler>(); // I want Name property to be 'twitter'
```

Is there a way to achieve this without doing:

```
services.AddHttpClient("github")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.github.com"); })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(provider =>
    {
        var logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MessageHandler>>();
        var someService = provider.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();
        return new MessageHandler(logger, someService, "github");
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

Given that the original example has the following constructor

```
public MessageHandler(ILogger<MessageHandler> logger, ISomeService someService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _someService = someService;
}
```

You could just resolve the handler and then set the property

```
services.AddTransient<MessageHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("github")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => { c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.github.com"); })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(provider => {
        var handler = provider.GetRequiredService<MessageHandler>();
        handler.Name = "github";
        return handler;
    });
```

Either way you would need to manually resolve the handler to be able to set that string property.